# Align equation, matrix, and table

Tags: tables, align, matrices

I need to align this equation as:

[image]

I recreated it by using the equation, matrix, and tabular environment.

```
\begin{equation} \hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c }
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{0} & 0\ 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{0} \\ & 1\ 0 &  &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{0} & \multirow{3}{*}{0} & 0\ \ $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0 & \multirow{3}{*}{0} \\ &  & $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0\ $\sqrt{2}$ & \\ & & 0\ \ $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0 &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & 0\ $\sqrt{3}$\ 0\ 0 &  \\
    & & & $\sqrt{3}$\ 0\ 2\ 0 & \\
    & & & 0\ 2\ 0\ $\sqrt{3}$ & \\
    & & & 0\ 0\ $\sqrt{3}$\ 0&  \\ \hline
    & & & & $\ddots$ \\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

I am getting this:

[image]

But I need the first part of the equation to be aligned on the top left. Also the alignment in the table is a bit off. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `tabular` but `array` (essentially the same as `tabular` but for maths).

Comment: @Evan I am sorry for a not latex related comment but... Is this related to quantum chemistry and magnetism? I remember similar matrices coming from Pauli matrices when calculating interaction hamiltionans for higher spins. Ising model... this sort of stuff? It just brings back PhD memories...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `delarray` for top aligning the matrix and `gathered` for centering the equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
\begin{array}[t]({ c | c | c | c | c })
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vphantom{\Big|} \\
\hline
0 & \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} & 0 &  &  \\
\hline
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix}
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
        \end{matrix} & 0 & \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & \begin{matrix}
            0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
            \sqrt{3} & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
            0 & 2 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \\
            0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0
            \end{matrix} & \\
\hline
    & & & & \ddots
\end{array}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Nesting matrices is much easier than abusing `\multirow`.

[image]

Removing `gathered` yields

[image]

On the other hand, I don't think this is really clear.

In case you change your mind:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
\left(\begin{array}{ @{} c | c | c | c | c @{} }
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vphantom{\Big|} \\
\hline
0 & \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} & 0 &  &  \\
\hline
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix}
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
        \end{matrix} & 0 & \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & \begin{matrix}
            0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
            \sqrt{3} & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
            0 & 2 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \\
            0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0
            \end{matrix} & \\
\hline
    & & & & \ddots
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can obtain a more open look by setting `\extrarowheight`. I'll only show it added to the last code, the method applies the same for the other two examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
\left(\begin{array}{ @{} c | c | c | c | c @{} }
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vphantom{\Big|} \\
\hline
0 & \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} & 0 &  &  \\
\hline
0 & 0 & \begin{matrix}
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
        \end{matrix} & 0 & \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & \begin{matrix}
            0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
            \sqrt{3} & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
            0 & 2 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \\
            0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0
            \end{matrix} & \\
\hline
    & & & & \ddots
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Done in a different way

Comment: your first answer looks exactly like what I want but the ( ) after the \begin{array} don't work.

Comment: @Evan Did you add `\usepackage{delarray}`?

Comment: I did, once I delete the () around ({ c | c | c | c | c }) it works but the table is not in brackets of course. Your second answer works but the alignment before the table is in the middle.

Comment: @Evan I suspect that there's something else going on. Does compiling the exact same code in my example work?

Comment: No, only if I delete the () around ({ c | c | c | c | c }). The code in your second answer works,,, \left(\begin{array}{ @{} c | c | c | c | c @{} }\right)

Comment: @Evan I can't think of a reason; I copied and pasted back the code, it works flawlessly on my machine. What happens to you when you have `(` and `)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83899/discussion-between-evan-and-egreg).

Comment: The answer works perfectly . Some of my previous commands were preventing it from working.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the eq number aligned with the top, then just place the `pmatrix` in a `\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{$\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c }
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{0} & 0\ 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{0} \\ & 1\ 0 &  &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{0} & \multirow{3}{*}{0} & 0\ \ $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0 & \multirow{3}{*}{0} \\ &  & $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0\ $\sqrt{2}$ & \\ & & 0\ \ $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0 &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & 0\ $\sqrt{3}$\ 0\ 0 &  \\
    & & & $\sqrt{3}$\ 0\ 2\ 0 & \\ 
    & & & 0\ 2\ 0\ $\sqrt{3}$ & \\
    & & & 0\ 0\ $\sqrt{3}$\ 0&  \\ \hline
    & & & & $\ddots$ \\ 
  \end{tabular}
  \end{pmatrix}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the number centered, then just wrap the whole thing in a `\vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle...$}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \vcenter{\hbox{$\displaystyle\hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{$\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c }
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{0} & 0\ 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{0} \\ & 1\ 0 &  &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{0} & \multirow{3}{*}{0} & 0\ \ $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0 & \multirow{3}{*}{0} \\ &  & $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0\ $\sqrt{2}$ & \\ & & 0\ \ $\sqrt{2}$\ \ 0 &  \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & 0\ $\sqrt{3}$\ 0\ 0 &  \\
    & & & $\sqrt{3}$\ 0\ 2\ 0 & \\ 
    & & & 0\ 2\ 0\ $\sqrt{3}$ & \\
    & & & 0\ 0\ $\sqrt{3}$\ 0&  \\ \hline
    & & & & $\ddots$ \\ 
  \end{tabular}
  \end{pmatrix}$}$}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\raisebox{-\height}` to lower the box to move it below the baseline and `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip\relax}` to get it on the correct height:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \hat{J}_x \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{2}
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip\relax}
    {%
      $\begin{pmatrix}
      \begin{array}{ c | c | c | c | c }
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{0} & 0\ 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \multirow{2}{*}{0} \\ & 1\ 0 &  &  \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{0} & \multirow{3}{*}{0} & 0\ \ \sqrt{2}\ \ 0 & \multirow{3}{*}{0} \\ &  & \sqrt{2}\ \ 0\ \sqrt{2} & \\ & & 0\ \ \sqrt{2}\ \ 0 &  \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & \multirow{4}{*}{0} & 0\ \sqrt{3}\ 0\ 0 &  \\
        & & & \sqrt{3}\ 0\ 2\ 0 & \\ 
        & & & 0\ 2\ 0\ \sqrt{3} & \\
        & & & 0\ 0\ \sqrt{3}\ 0&  \\ \hline
        & & & & \ddots \\ 
      \end{array}
      \end{pmatrix}$%
    }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]